# Bar chart: x-axis not mapping properly

Tags: r, ggplot2

[This is what the current bar chart looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/btTDO.png)

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
```

Say I have a dataframe called abc, and under the dataframe there's a variable called prolvl. I have been trying to display this variable in ggplot as a bar chart:

```
ggplot(data = abc, mapping = aes(x = prolvl)) +
  geom_bar(position = "dodge")
```

prolvl has values of "protest", "no protest", "slight protest" under it. When I test the type of prolvl it shows as character.

However, when I look at the output I see a barchart with only one variable "Protest Level" (it doesn't separate out by the different subvariables within it).

Could you please help me fix this?

Comment: Can you supply a basic dataframe that demonstrates your problem?

Comment: I don't know how to write it out so I'll just make it seem like one here

dataframe abc:

variable 1 = condition variable 2 = prolvl
1) Group, No Protest
2) Individual, Protest
3) Group, Protest
4) Individual, Protest
5) Individual, No Protest
6) Group, Slight Protest
7) Group, Protest
8) Individual, No Protest

and it would have about 50 of these..?

Comment: Well, it could be that your dataframe is not arranged correctly - wide vs long perhaps, or it could be that some other variable is not usable for the graphing.

Comment: Is there a variable type you should use for the x-axis when the variable is discrete? Right now it's shown as character

Comment: This is the reason you get told to supply a [minimal complete working example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `geom_bar` uses `stat.count` to add the variables together - perhaps you have the data arranged the wrong way, we can't help troubleshoot unless you show us what you have done. Part of this is supplying some of the data set, or data that demonstrates the same problem (i.e. it doesn't have to be your actual data, just some that shows the same problem).

Comment: Would it be something like this??
```
abc <- data.frame(condition=c(group, individual), prolvl=c(protest, no protest, slight protest))
```
I'm importing the data from an external csv file--sorry I couldn't provide a way it would have been written out in r

Comment: Try something like `dput(head(abc, 10))`.